# Объясните неграмотному, как сравнить два изображения в opencv и получить значение как на картинке и добавить больше различий

Tags: python, opencv, сравнение

Есть две картинки, нужно в python opencv сравнить две картинки и получить результат как на скриншоте ниже, различия нужно добавить в красный прямоугольник, так же как на скриншоте. Нужно найти максимум 4-5 отличий и передвинуть их вправо, если можно добавить стрелочки как на скриншоте 2. Звучит очень сложно, поэтому и спрашиваю у вас=)

[image: Скриншот 1]  [image: Скриншот 2]

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Попробуйте наложить две картинки друг на друга, при этом несовпадающие пиксели будут закрашены каким-то цветом. После можно найти координаты этих закрашенных пикселей и нарисовать прямоугольник. И так повторять. С прямоугольниками та же история, ищите их, копируете и помещаете справа.